# $F(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \sqrt {\arctan {t}}dt$ is bounded for $x \ge 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

> $F(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \sqrt {\arctan {t}}\space dt$ is bounded for $x \ge 0$.

My attempt is $\sqrt {\arctan {t}}$ is continuous, therefore Riemann integrable and so $F(x)$ is continuous. $F(x)$ is continuous on closed interval so it's bounded.

Comment: Where is the $dx$?  Do you want the $x$ on the integrand to be the same as the $x$ inside the arctan?

Comment: Continuity does not matter that much: the length of the integration range is one and the integrand function is non-negative and bounded by a constant, $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: And plenty of functions are continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and not bounded there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral should (probably) read $F(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \sqrt{\arctan t} \, dt$.

If $x > 0$ then $0 < \arctan x < \frac \pi 2$. Thus $0 < F(x) < \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2}}$.